# How do I conditionally format to highlight cells with =-IF in the formula?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007, microsoft-excel-2016, conditional-formatting

I have a large workbook with many sheets, each with two sections in them. 
One section, the formulas should begin

```
=IF(ISNA(...
```

and in the other section the formulas should begin

```
=-IF(ISNA(...
```

How can I create a conditional formatting to highlight cells in each section where they do NOT follow the respective `IF`/`-IF` formula pattern?

Answer (score 0):

I think I might have solved my own problem, at least until someone lets me know of a better way!

https://uhasct.com/find-inconsistent-use-of-formulas-in-excel-columns/

Using the Go To > Special, and selecting Column Differences. Then highlighting the differences